# C++20 Coroutines and iostream

Tags: c++, iostream, clang++, c++-coroutine

I am playing around with C++ 20's Coroutines. The sample is compiled with clang++.

The compiler error I am facing is

> error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka
> 'basic_ostream') and 'cppcoro::generator')

which is about the following line

```
std::cout << numbers << " ";
```

the full code snipped looks like this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cppcoro/generator.hpp>

using namespace std;

// coroutine
cppcoro::generator<int> generatorForNumbers(int begin, int inc = 1) 
{
  // for Schleife ohne Abbruchbedingung
  for (int i = begin;; i += inc) 
  {
    co_yield i;
  }  
}

int main() 
{

    auto numbers = generatorForNumbers(-10);                 
  
    for (int i= 1; i <= 20; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << numbers << " ";       
    }
  
    std::cout << "\n\n";
        
    // inline works
    for (auto n: generatorForNumbers(0, 5))
    {
        std::cout << n << " ";  
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Executable code snipped can be found here:
https://godbolt.org/z/4cxhqxPP7

Comment: first time I see coroutines in action. I took a look at the header and I can understand how the ranged based loop is working, but why `std::cout << numbers << " ";` should work, I dont understand. Do you have some reference that says this should be fine?

Comment: indeed: https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-20-coroutines-the-first-overview

Comment: It's possible the article meant to do `cout << numbers()` like some other languages do it. It'd be mistaken (for this generator type specifically; another one could support that), but it's possible that's what the intent was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [cppcoro::generator](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro#generatort), the only "meaningful" operations you can do to a generator is get begin and end iterators via `begin()` and `end()`. This is precisely why your second use `for (auto n : generatorForNumbers(0, 5))` works. It iterates over the generator. Though you technically hit undefined behavior since there's no stopping condition for the generator so it overflows an `int`.

You can't print the generator directly. You have to iterate over it. So you could do this instead:

```
auto numbers = generatorForNumbers(-10);

auto it = numbers.begin();
for (int i= 1; i <= 20; ++i)
{
    std::cout << *it << " ";
    ++it;
}
```

or better (in my opinion):

```
int i = 0;
for (auto n : generatorForNumbers(-10))
{
    if (++i > 20)
        break;
    std::cout << n << " ";
}
```

or even better using ranges (thanks to @cigien in the comments):

```
for (auto n : generatorForNumbers(-10) | std::views::take(20))
{
    std::cout << n << " ";
}
```

Comment: `for (auto n : generatorForNumbers(-10) | std::views::take(20))` should work as well I think.

Comment: that looks very good, thank you. There is still no gcc support for this, isn't it?

Comment: @cigien Much better! I haven't played around with ranges myself so I wasn't familiar with how to use them